# Text with Transparent BSDF and Black Diffuse BDSF not fully transparent

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, video-sequence-editor, transparency, compositing-nodes

I spent the entire day trying to figure this one out. I'm using cycles.

I'm trying to make subtitles for a video. The reason I'm using blender for this is because I have to hide previous subtitles and because I am familiar with the software. To hide the previous subtitles I used planes.

Usually I don't have this problem. But it looks like today nothing wants to be fully transparent. I made a plane with a spherical gradient and the alpha parts of it were leaving a black shadow on my footage (the alpha was supposed to be gradient white to transparent. No shadow or anything.)

Nevermind the plane problem, although it would be nice to fix it, I can live with that.

The real problem is my text:

[image: textatbottomoffootage]

You can see the text looks like a watermark instead of fully disappearing.
Here is the setup:

[image: nodes]

If you look at the material sphere it doesn't disappear entirely either.
I think this is because I am trying to fade black text. Black doesn't fade entirely?

I tried many different node setups. Also tried using a black transparent BSDF in the mix and even using a transparent BSDF with no mix shader.

Nothing seems to work. I've done 3d animation with blender from scratch, with my own models and everything. I'm at a loss with this, spent the entire day on it and just can't figure out why my text won't disappear.
I've already done subtitles before and never ran into this issue. It's driving me nuts.

I'm considering just rendering my subtitles as separate images and overlaying that because I've already wasted too much time on this.

How can I make black text disappear entirely?...

Comment: Can you add your node setup, so we can tweak it.

Comment: You can see the node setup on the right hand side of the second screenshot. It's just a basic setup with 1 mix shader node connected to the material output and 1 transparent bsdf at the top input of the mix shader and 1 diffuse bsdf at the bottom input of the mix shader.